# is "from flask import request" identical to "import requests"?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

In other words, is the flask request class identical to the requests library?

I consulted:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

but cannot tell for sure. I see code examples where people seem to use them interchangeably.

Comment: these are two different libraries.

Comment: The first link is no longer working.

Answer (score 76):

No these are not only completely different libraries, but completely different purposes.

Flask is a web framework which clients make requests to. The Flask `request` object contains the data that the client (eg a browser) has sent to your app - ie the URL parameters, any POST data, etc.

The requests library is for your app to make HTTP request to *other* sites, usually APIs. It makes an outgoing request and returns the response from the external site.

Comment: So if needs to both send data to a website and then accept and process the "request" data between flask application processes they should be given aliases? or....

Comment: This needs to be pinned for beginners in web development like me. Many thanks.