# ImportError: cannot import name 'request' from 'flask'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, token

While running a py file through Pycharm I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'request' from 'flask'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/smilecook-test-L_1-4/resources/token.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import request
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/smilecook-test-L_1-4/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/smilecook-test-L_1-4/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .serving import run_simple as run_simple
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/smilecook-test-L_1-4/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 16, in <module>
    import platform
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/platform.py", line 116, in <module>
    import sys, os, re, subprocess
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 155, in <module>
    import threading
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 8, in <module>
    from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/smilecook-test-L_1-4/resources/token.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import request
ImportError: cannot import name 'request' from 'flask' (/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/smilecook-test-L_1-4/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's the code:

```
from http import HTTPStatus
from flask import request
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask_jwt_extended import (
    create_access_token,
    jwt_refresh_token_required,
    create_refresh_token,
    get_jwt_identity,
    jwt_required,
    get_raw_jwt
)

from utils import check_password
from models.user import User

black_list = set()


class TokenResource(Resource):

    def post(self):

        json_data = request.get_json()

        email = json_data.get('email')
        password = json_data.get('password')

        user = User.get_by_email(email=email)

        if not user or not check_password(password, user.password):
            return {'message': 'username or password is incorrect'}, HTTPStatus.UNAUTHORIZED

        access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.id, fresh=True)
        refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=user.id)

        return {'access_token': access_token, 'refresh_token': refresh_token}, HTTPStatus.OK


class RefreshResource(Resource):

    @jwt_refresh_token_required
    def post(self):
        current_user = get_jwt_identity()

        token = create_access_token(identity=current_user, fresh=False)

        return {'token': token}, HTTPStatus.OK


class RevokeResource(Resource):

    @jwt_required
    def post(self):
        jti = get_raw_jwt()['jti']

        black_list.add(jti)

        return {'message': 'Successfully logged out'}, HTTPStatus.OK
```

As far as I know the Flask request object contains the data that the client (eg a browser) sends to an app (URL parameters, POST data, etc.)
as stated here: [is "from flask import request" identical to "import requests"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319070/is-from-flask-import-request-identical-to-import-requests)

Answer (score 2):

You have a circular import. This is caused by the fact that your `token` module shadows a standard library module. From the traceback:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/smilecook-test-L_1-4/resources/token.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import request
```

The module `tokenize.py` is looking for a `token.py` and gets your file instead of the standard library one. It notices that the requested import is the one being processed and fails.

Rename your file `token.py`.

Comment: Actually it works...great